# What is the correct way to create object with relationship in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I've two models, Parent and Child over a SQLite db.

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'PARENTS'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False, sqlite_on_conflict_unique='IGNORE')
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'CHILDREN'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('PARENTS.id'), nullable=False)
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
```

I need to create children like the following:

`session.add(Child(name="...",parent=Parent(name="..."))`,
that is I want to create a child having its name and the name of the parent. I would like to know which is the best way to do this. Can I instruct SA to go and select Parents for me retrieving the parent.id from parent.name? Can I leverage some sort of caching mechanism for not having the parent table queried for each adding child (parent changes seldom). I don't need to create a new parent when I create a new child, but I want it to be linked to an already existing parent. Moreover I need to have long lists of children to be created fastly (e.g. for seeding the db).

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to uniquely identify a Parent object by its `.name` then "name" should be the primary key of the "PARENTS" table. That is, you should use a natural primary key instead of an auto-incremented numeric primary key (`id`).

Comment: Thanks, but the "name" field actually doesn't exists, it corresponds in my real code to a set of columns that are unique. I just simplified it to ask the question. My question was about the correct way to have sqlalchemy querying the parent table, identifying the correct one (based on primary or on a set of condition) and using its id inside child object. The equivalent of INSERT-INTO-SELECT query but all inside SA and possibly caching parents for not to repeat the query for every child. Thanks.

Comment: One thing you could do would be to create a `dict` where the keys are the parent "name" and the values are the corresponding parent "id". When you go to create the child you could look up the parent "name" in the dict and use the "id" if it is already there, otherwise hit the parent table to retrieve the "id" and add it to the dict. In other words, you could build yourself a simple cache to maintain that mapping without hitting the parent table every time.

Comment: Ok, so I have to manage it on my own. Thanks!